# How to call C lib file functions from java

Tags: java, c

I have a .lib C file with functions. I have a list of all the functions name and I don't know how to call / access those functions from java. I don't have any language in C programming language but have got good skills in java. I am stuck and I don't know where to begin.

Comment: Try [this famous site](https://www.google.nl/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=use%20c%20in%20java) or [this](http://stuf.ro/calling-c-code-from-java-using-jni)

Answer (score 1):

You can eventually use the Java Native Interface. Here is a tutorial which may help you to start:

https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/JavaNativeInterface.html